# Using Drupal for Software As A Service

Tags: commerce

I want to build a product where separate organizations will have their separate data ( content , users, etc.) Is it possible using drupal ? If yes, how should I begin?
I have made community websites in drupal but in these ,only one database table is used. how to use different databases for different organizations? 
Thank you!

Comment: Where is the SAAS part ? What you described looks more like a [multisite](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) install.

Comment: I guess multisite install is manual...I mean create a new site folder every time an organization registers.. I wanted it to do it automatically...